# Neo4J OGM: relationships between nodes becomes nodes with edges to the entities (nodes)

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I am using Spring Boot and OGM. I have a @Nodeentity (Person) and a @RelationshipEntity (Familyrelation) with a type. When I put together nodes and relationships (a simple family-relationship between two persons), I get four nodes and the property of the two "extra" nodes is the relationship-id. Here is the code (excerpt):

```java
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Person, Long> {

}

@Data
@Slf4j
@NodeEntity("Person")
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private int age;

  @Relationship(type = "FAMILY")
  private Set<Familyrelation> relations = new HashSet<>();

  public Set<Familyrelation> getRelations() {
    return relations;
  }

  public void setRelasjon(Familyrelation relasjon) {
    this.relations.add(relasjon);
  }

  //Hashcode and equals omitted

@RelationshipEntity(type = "FAMILY")
public class Familyrelation {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long relationshipId;
  @StartNode
  private Person person;
  @EndNode
  private Person relatedPerson;


  public void setPerson(final Person person) {
    this.person = person;
  }

  public void setRelatedPerson(final Person relatedPerson) {
    this.relatedPerson = relatedPerson;
  }

//Omitted hashcode, equals and other getters/setters
```

Here is how I create the graph:

```java
 final Person person1 = new Person();
 person1.setName("Bob");
 person1.setAge(40);

 final Person person2 = new Person();
 person2.setName("Alice");
 person2.setAge(30);

 final Familyrelation familierelasjon1 = new Familyrelation();
 familierelasjon1.setPerson(person1);
 familierelasjon1.setRelatedPerson(person2);
 final Familyrelation familierelasjon2 = new Familyrelation();
 familierelasjon2.setPerson(person2);
 familierelasjon2.setRelatedPerson(person1);

 person1.setRelasjon(familierelasjon1);
 person2.setRelasjon(familierelasjon2);

 personRepository.save(person1);
 personRepository.save(person2);
```

[image: Relationship is becoming a node]

What am I missing here?

EDIT: omitting persisting person2 will yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have choosen to add so-called "rich relationships" (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/4.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#__relationshipentity_rich_relationships). Omitting this relationship class will yield only edges between nodes. So instead of having a set with relationships, modify the set to contain Person.

Change this

```java
@Relationship(type = "FAMILY")
  private Set<Familyrelation> relations = new HashSet<>();
```

to

```java
@Relationship(type = "FAMILY")
  private Set<Person> relations = new HashSet<>();
```

```java
final Person2 person1 = new Person2();
    person1.setName("Bob");
    person1.setAge(40);

    final Person2 person2 = new Person2();
    person2.setName("Alice");
    person2.setAge(30);

    person1.setRelasjon(person2);
    person2.setRelasjon(person1);

    personRepository.save(person1);
```

This will yield nodes with edges connected to them.

[image: No rich relationships]

Comment: Furthermore, I am using `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j:2.6.0` and this version does not support Neo4j-OGM. This means that the annotations from OGM doesn't have any effect, hence Neo is treating every POJO as an entity.